# Write several strings in one cell

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, concatenation, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a function that looks for several categories codes in a cell and then writes the appropriate category Manager for each in a different cell. In the end there should be a collection of comma separated strings representing the managers' names. For example: :

```
Column Categories: 3AF,5CB,4DF,5GK 

Manager Names:     Dieter, Max
```

My approach:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("4DF";A1);0);"Dieter";IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("5GK";A1);0);"Max";""))
```

It's working fine (finds both names) but it only writes the first string that is found (`Dieter` above) and does not show manager names found later (ie not `Max`). So I'm looking for a modification that fills the new cell with *both* names.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I simply want some help to achieve this since I couldnt find related Topics on the Internet. I dont know what you want to tell me with this post.

Comment: Well, that tag was a mistake then....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present the formula might be read as “If this true do *that*, otherwise if something different is true do *the other*”, so the result can only be *that* OR *the other*. To achieve both *that* and *the other* in the same cell only an adjustment to concatenate the two results is required.

The shortest way to [CONCATENATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/concatenate-HP005209020.aspx) is with `&` but to take the opportunity to add a comma and space between the results, with `&", "` thus:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("4DF";A1);0),"Dieter")&", "&IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("5GK";A1);0);"Max";"")
```

The principle could be extended to include further results, say if the column category is `3AF` and the Manager `Julian`, like so:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("4DF";A1);0);"Dieter")&", "&IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("5GK";A1);0);"Max";"")&"; "&IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("3AF";A1);0);"Julian";"")
```

[SEARCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/search.php) is **not** case sensitive so will treat `4df` the same as `4DF`. However SEARCH always counts each character, whether single-byte or double-byte, as 1, no matter what the default language setting is so for double-byte characters [SEARCHB](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/search-searchb-functions-HP010062577.aspx) might be a more appropriate alternative in other cases.

In the above though the position of the characters in the string (which is what SEARCH seeks to return) is not relevant since these formulae happen only need to see if present *anywhere* in the string. If not present an error ([#VALUE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZbVB_aXziA)) would be triggered but this is caught and converted to `0` by the [IFERROR](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/iferror-for-excel-2003/b5cd6d85-24a4-4a8f-9db0-6c93b533afe9) trap. Hence if say the `Column Categories` had been `3AF,5CB,9ZZ,5GK` the longest formula above would return:

> 0, Max, Julian

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed explanaiton!